# Plymouth: disable status messages

Tags: password, luks, plymouth

I installed Plymouth on a LUKS encrypted machine. Works fine. Theme is Spinner, in case it matters.

I'd like to modify one thing, though:

After entering the LUKS passphrase, there's a status message `cryptsetup: nvme0n1p3_crypt set up successfully` showing for 2-3 seconds. Is it possible to get rid of it? In `/usr/share/plymouth/themes/spinner/spinner.plymouth` there is a `MessageBelowAnimation=true` option, but that's just for the position on the screen. Is it possible to completely hide the status messages?